# Redirect error of child script in bash to a function in parent script

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I want to redirect the error of my java call (beeline) in a bash script to a function in the same bash script. How can it be done?

```
beeline -u "${!DestHiveJdbcUrl}" -n hive -p hive -e "use $DatabaseName ; MSCK REPAIR TABLE $TableName" 2>&1 | PrtLog e
```

I want to log error like

```
"Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: prod_corporate_parameters_tets (state=42000,code=10072)"
```

`PrtLog` is my function and `e` is a argument signifying my function that this is an error. But my above approach is not working. Any Idea where i'm wrong? My PrtLog function is below. Msg variable captures log message.

```
    PrtLog() {
        Msg=$2
        case $1 in
        'i')
                Severity='INFO '
                ThisCode=0
                lLevel=10
                ;;
        'e')
                Severity='ERROR'
                ThisCode=1
                lLevel=0
                ;;
        'd')
                Severity='DEBUG'
                ThisCode=0
                lLevel=30
                ;;
        'w')
                Severity='WARN '
                ThisCode=0
                lLevel=20
                ;;
        't')
                Severity='TRACE'
                ThisCode=0
                lLevel=40
                ;;
        *)
                Severity='UNKWN'
                ThisCode=1
                lLevel=0
                ;;
        esac

   if [ $RetCode -lt $ThisCode ]; then
      RetCode=$ThisCode
   fi
   if [ $lLevel -le $vDebLevel ]; then
      echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"` - `hostname` - $ScrName - $vPid - "$Severity" - $Msg | tee -a ${LogFile}
   fi
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your problem, to act on simple shell commands, every user has? Or do you believe it is a sideeffect of using beeline and PrtLog? Something like fun1 2>&1 | fun2. Then we should know what they are, but installing a database, to test it, is out of practical. See [mcve] for a longer explanation.

Comment: When an user passes wrong arguments to the beeline command or the beeline command fails to execute, i want to log it using the PrtLog function.Example logs are below.

Comment: What does it mean "is not working"? Writes elsewhere, writes nothing at all, segfaults, bash-error message, conditions not met, ...? We don't have a crystal ball to know this. Can you reproduce the problem with a simple mocking function instead of using beeline? Problem isolation is a part of problem solving.

Comment: writes nothing and this results in having a nonzero return code

Comment: I did try with other command called distcp instead of beeline and it also has the same issue. It just passes a blank line to PrtLog function as message. "2018/03/05 13:38:50 - localhost- Distcp_MSCK - 28796 - ERROR -          "

Comment: I think I haven't been clear enough. Your question shows an long parametrized call to beeline with output redirection and a pipe to PrtLog e. Do I need to know something about beeline? Do the parameters care? Then we have the PrtLog function with multiple cases. Do they matter? In the end there is a long list of parameters with date and so on again. Are they required to reproduce the problem? How much time do I have to spend, to figure out, what your problem is? Wouldn't a short mocking program `echo "error" >&2; echo "output"` be enough to test the problem?

Comment: Strip your problem to the bare minimum (who cares about the date? If it works without the date, it will work with the date), so that it fits into few, short lines.

Answer (score 0):

You call beeline, whatever it is:

```
beeline -u "${!DestHiveJdbcUrl}" -n hive -p hive -e "use $DatabaseName ; MSCK REPAIR TABLE $TableName" 2>&1 | PrtLog e
```

and beeline produces eventually an errormessage which you combine with the stdout and pipe it to the function PrtLog, which you call with Parameter e.

Now PrtLog expects 2 paramter, Msg and the case switcher, which was 'e':

PrtLog() {
        Msg=$2
        case $1 in
        'e')
                Severity='ERROR'
                ThisCode=1
                lLevel=0
                ;;
        esac

and then we have

```
   if [ $RetCode -lt $ThisCode ]; then
      RetCode=$ThisCode
   fi
   if [ $lLevel -le $vDebLevel ]; then
      echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"` - `hostname` - $ScrName - $vPid - "$Severity" - $Msg | tee -a ${LogFile}
   fi
```

We don't know what RetCode is, it's undocumented. Might be ThisCode after the first branch, which should be 1.

lLevel is 0 and should be checked against vDebLevel. We don't know, what vDebLevel is. A global variable.

Then we have archaic backtick calls to date, which don't matter here, like $(hostname), unknown stuff, $Severity which should be Error right now, and $Msg which is empty, because we only got one parameter, remember:

```
... | PrtLog e
```

This is tee-appended to some LogFile via a pipe.

> Msg variable captures log message.

No. It doesn't. 
Msg is the second parameter the function expects, but is was called with one parameter.

Either you capture the output of your beeprogram:

```
msg=$(beeline -u "${!D...l}" -n hive -p hive -e "use ..." 2>&1)
PrtLog e "msg"
```

Or you pipe the output of the program to the function, but then the function has to read from from STDIN:

```
while ... 
   read line 
   ... do something with $line
done
```

You can't expect the function expecting a parameter at input position or vice versa.

Your problem has nothing to do with beeline. Learn to identify your problem.

To reproduce the problem, you just need a program, which produces output on stdout and stderr:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# write to err and out
#
echo "error" >&2; 
echo "output"
```

Let's call it beelinemock.sh.

```
chmod a+x beelinemock.sh
./beelinemock.sh 
error
output
```

Test, whether it works:

```
./beelinemock.sh 2>/dev/null
output

./beelinemock.sh 1>/dev/null
error
```

Right?

Now take it as source for the PrtLog:

```
./beelinemock.sh  2>&1 | PrtLog e
```

Now simplify the whole script, just try some random numbers for RetCode and vDebLevel:

```
LogFile=prtlog.log
RetCode=33
vDebLevel=7

PrtLog() {
        Msg=$2
        case $1 in
        'e')
                Severity=ERROR
                ThisCode=1
                lLevel=0
                ;;
       esac

       if [ $RetCode -lt $ThisCode ]; then
          RetCode=$ThisCode
       fi
       if [ $lLevel -le $vDebLevel ]; then
          echo $(date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") - $(hostname) - "$Severity" - $Msg | tee -a ${LogFile}
       fi
}

./beelinemock.sh  2>&1 | PrtLog e
```

Output:

```
2018/03/05 15:46:37 - tux201t - ERROR -
```

No Message, as expected.

Modify the last line:

```
msg=$(./beelinemock.sh  2>&1)
PrtLog e "$msg"
```

Output:

```
2018/03/05 15:48:17 - tux201t - ERROR - error output
```

Here is the message.

With a pipe:

```
LogFile=prtlog.log
RetCode=33
vDebLevel=7

PrtLog() {
        case $1 in
        'e')
                Severity=ERROR
                ThisCode=1
                lLevel=0
                ;;
       esac

       if [ $RetCode -lt $ThisCode ]; then
          RetCode=$ThisCode
       fi
       if [ $lLevel -le $vDebLevel ]; then {
          echo $(date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") - $(hostname) - "$Severity" - $Msg

          while read line
          do
            echo $line
          done

       } | tee -a ${LogFile}
       fi
}

./beelinemock.sh  2>&1 | PrtLog e
```

Output:

```
2018/03/05 15:50:56 - tux201t - ERROR -
error
output
```

Nobody is willing to issue a "MSCK REPAIR $Tablename" on his data to test your script. With "beeline" you lose 90% of your audience "Don't know, can't help", so people leave, because you need to work 5 Minutes or more through the code to find out, it is very irrelevant for the syntactic part of the problem, while it is, of course, on the semantic level.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will try your recommendations.